# Route not seeing URL slug

Tags: ember.js

I have an app that allows management of orders. The default view is a split view with orders on the left and selected order details on the right like so:

```
  /Orders        /Orders/:order_id
|-----------| |-------------------------------------|
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|  List of  | |           Selected Item             |
|   Items   | |              Details                |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|           | |                                     |
|-----------| |-------------------------------------|
```

I'd like to be able to edit an order in "full-screen" mode so that the URL and template looks like this:

```
  /Orders/:order_id/edit/
|---------------------------------------------------|
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|           Order Edit Interface                    |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

My routes are currently setup as follows:

```
this.resource('Orders.edit', { path: 'Orders/:order_id/edit' } , function () {
    this.route('customer-details');
    this.route('vendor-details');
    this.route('shipping-details');
}

this.resource('Orders', { path: 'Orders' }, function () {
    this.resource('Order', { path: ':order_id' }, function () {
        this.route('customer-details');
        this.route('vendor-details');
        this.route('shipping-details');
    }
}
```

And my order routes look like this:

```
// Orders Route
App.OrdersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('order');
    },

    afterModel: function (orders) {
        this.transitionTo('orders.order', orders.get('firstObject') );
    }
});

// Order Detail
App.OrdersOrderRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('order', params.order);
    },

    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});

// Order Edit Route
App.OrdersEditRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        if (typeof params.order_id !== 'undefined') {
            this.store.find('order', params.order_id).then(function (order) {
                this.controllerFor('orders.edit').set('content', order);
            });
        } else if (typeof params.order !== 'undefined') {
            this.store.find('order', params.order).then(function (order) {
                this.controllerFor('orders.edit').set('content', order);
            });
        }
    },

    afterModel: function(eo) {
        this.transitionTo('orders.edit.customer-details', order);
    }
});

// Order Edit - Customer Details Route
App.OrdersEditCustomerDetailsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        try {
            var order = this.get('order');
            return order;

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
        }
    },

    beforeModel: function() {
        this.set('order', this.modelFor('orders.edit'));
    },
});
```

This setup works if I'm in the `Orders/:order_id` route/template and click the edit button which then sends me to `Orders/:order_id/edit` with the desired interface and data loaded. But if I try to refresh `Orders/:order_id/edit` in the browser window nothing loads and I get the following errors. I also don't hit any breakpoints set inside of the `Orders/:order_id/edit` route when accessing the URL this way.

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('classification', N/A) to the 'content' property of object proxy <Synapse.EngineeringOrdersEditDetailsController:ember1242>: its 'content' is undefined. libs.js:2870
    Ember.assert libs.js:2870
    EmberObject.extend.setUnknownProperty libs.js:23933
    set libs.js:9229
    setPath libs.js:9289
    set libs.js:9209
    trySet libs.js:9306
    (anonymous function) libs.js:3416
    tryable libs.js:5964
    tryFinally libs.js:10524
    suspendListener libs.js:5967
    _suspendObserver libs.js:8311
    Binding._sync libs.js:3415
    DeferredActionQueues.invoke libs.js:11346
    DeferredActionQueues.flush libs.js:11398
    Backburner.end libs.js:10861
    Backburner.run libs.js:10916
    apply libs.js:10745
    run libs.js:9378
    runInitialize libs.js:45596
    n.Callbacks.j libs.js:2
    n.Callbacks.k.fireWith libs.js:2
    n.extend.ready libs.js:2
    I libs.js:2

TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at http://localhost:1337/js/app.js:27936:22
        at invokeCallback (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:13310:19)
        at publish (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:12980:9)
        at publishFulfillment (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:13400:7)
        at http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:18818:9
        at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:11348:18)
        at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:11398:15)
        at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:10861:27)
        at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:10916:20)
        at executeTimers (http://localhost:1337/js/libs.js:11241:12) libs.js:6663
    logToConsole libs.js:6663
    RSVP.onerrorDefault libs.js:49435
    __exports__.default.trigger libs.js:12274
    Promise._onerror libs.js:12998
    publishRejection libs.js:13405
    (anonymous function) libs.js:18818
    DeferredActionQueues.invoke libs.js:11348
    DeferredActionQueues.flush libs.js:11398
    Backburner.end libs.js:10861
    Backburner.run libs.js:10916
    executeTimers libs.js:11241
    (anonymous function) libs.js:11231

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: undefined is not a function libs.js:2870
    Ember.assert libs.js:2870
    RSVP.onerrorDefault libs.js:49436
    __exports__.default.trigger libs.js:12274
    Promise._onerror libs.js:12998
    publishRejection libs.js:13405
    (anonymous function) libs.js:18818
    DeferredActionQueues.invoke libs.js:11348
    DeferredActionQueues.flush libs.js:11398
    Backburner.end libs.js:10861
    Backburner.run libs.js:10916
    executeTimers libs.js:11241
    (anonymous function)
```

I suspect it has something to do with having the `Orders/order/edit` route outside the hierarchy of the Orders resource but I was unable to get the outlets to play nicely to render the desired interface.

TLDR - How do I get the `Orders/:order_id/edit` to load the model properly from the URL slug? Using Ember 1.6.1 and Ember-data Fixture Adapter

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ember.js but your second route treats :order_id as a parameter whereas your first (seems) to treat it as a literal.

Comment: I should be good with the slug. According to the docs at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments the `:` in `:order_id` identifies it as a slug. I could be missing something though

Comment: Can u creating a failing jsbin? Will make solving it a lot more easier

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with. The issue manifests itself when accessing the URL directly which is hard to replicate with a JSBin. I'll try a transition to the URL and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches to achieve what you describe are,

1. Separate resource for editing (basically along the lines if what you've tried)
2. Nested resource and maintain a property based on which the template will only render the outlet part or not.

Example of these two approaches,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wupiwoculoxi/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="orders">

{{#unless showOnlyEditDetail}}
orders

<br/>
{{#each order in model}}

{{#link-to "order" order.id}}

{{order.name}}
{{/link-to}}
<br/> <br/>

{{/each}}
{{/unless}}

{{!--the following lines before the outlet are shown on purpose for demonstration reasons, the unless helper in this example can hide anything on this template--}}
<hr/>
<i>the value of showOnlyEditDetail:</i><b>{{showOnlyEditDetail}}</b>

<hr/>

{{outlet}}

</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="order">
the order

<br/>
<br/>
{{this.id}}

<br/>
<br/>

{{this.name}}

<br/>
<br/>
{{#link-to "orderEdit" this.id }}edit1{{/link-to}}
<i>(separate resource)</i>

<br/>
<br/>
{{#link-to "orderEdit2" this.id }}edit2{{/link-to}}
<i>(nested resource and maintaining property)</i>
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="orderEdit">
edit the order

<br/>
{{this.id}}
<br/>
{{this.name}}
<br/>
{{#link-to "order" this.id}}back to the order{{/link-to}}
</script>



<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="orderEdit2">
edit2 the order

<br/>
{{this.id}}
<br/>
{{this.name}}
<br/>
{{#link-to "order" this.id}}back to the order{{/link-to}}
</script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {

  this.resource("orderEdit",{path:"orders/:order_id/edit"}, function(){

  });

  this.resource('orders', { path: 'orders' }, function () {

    this.resource('order', { path: ':order_id' }, function () {   
      this.route('customer-details'); 
      this.route('vendor-details'); 
      this.route('shipping-details'); 
    });


    this.resource("orderEdit2",{path:":order_id/edit2"}, function(){});
  });


});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo("orders");
  }
});


var ordersData=[
  {id:1,name:"order1"},
  {id:2,name:"order2"},
  {id:3,name:"order3"}
];


App.OrdersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ordersData;
  },
  setupController:function(c,m){
    c.set("showOnlyEditDetail",false);
    this._super(c,m);
  }
});

  /*if the second approach is used then the controller with the specific property 
  (i.e. showOnlyEditDetail) must be defined.*/
App.OrdersController=Em.ArrayController.extend({
  showOnlyEditDetail:false
});


App.OrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return ordersData.findBy("id",parseInt(params.order_id,10));
  }
});


App.OrderEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return ordersData.findBy("id",parseInt(params.order_id,10));
  }
});



App.OrderEdit2Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return ordersData.findBy("id",parseInt(params.order_id,10));
  },
  setupController:function(c,m){
    this._super(c,m);
    this.controllerFor("orders").set("showOnlyEditDetail",true);
  },
  actions:{
    willTransition:function(){
      this.controllerFor("orders").set("showOnlyEditDetail",false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @melc I'll give it a try as soon as I have a chance!

Comment: I have not yet been able to get your solution to work but I suspect it's more to do with my setup than your answer. Any ideas why a debug point inside the setupController hook on OrderEditRoute would never be hit? The `this.controllerFor('orders').set('showOnlyEditDetail', true);` line is never getting called so the template is rendering inside the outlet as opposed to in the full screen.

Comment: @ultimatemonty make sure the name conventions of routes are followed properly. Also make sure you choose one of the approaches as the example contains both. If it is not clear where exactly they separate let me know and I'll try to post two separate examples . I would also advise to follow the first approach first before trying the 2nd and maintaining a property.

Comment: I am able to get the first example to work if I `link-to` the edit route and pass the model in the `link-to`. If I try to directly open `orders/1/edit/details` in the browser the errors mentioned in the OP get thrown, the orderId (1) changes to undefined, and the application no longer works.

Comment: @ultimatemonty the first approach in the example works even if you go directly to the edit route. Try to modify the original code of the OP, accordingly. Try to return the model directly instead of trying to set the content to its controller....

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this - it's on my list to sort out when time permits. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: OK all of the sudden the first approach is working. I started having issues with node/grunt and rebuilding files/refreshing the browswer a few days ago and I wonder if those issues were causing things to go wonky. Regardless things are working now. Woohoo and thanks @melc!