# "Error while processing route" with unknown reason

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

**My Goal:** emulate nested route, but render it into application outlet.

For example:

/videos - top route

/videos/video001 - nested route

/videos/video001/slide001 - not nested. It is on the same level as /videos.

**How I am doing this:**

I have following router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('videos', { path: '/videos' }, function () {
        this.resource('video', { path: '/:video_id' });
    });

    this.resource('slide', { path: '/videos/:video_id/:slide_id' });
});
```

To make 'slide' route work as expected I am overriding 'serialize' method, and 
return 'video_id' and 'slide_id'

And at this point everything seems to be ok. At least page loads as expected.

**What is the issue?**

When I navigate to "/videos/video001" from "/videos/video001/slide001" via "link-to' helper,
I see following error: "Error while processing route: video".
And nothing more. I can't understand what kind of error happens and 
why ember can't process route correctly. However I see that URL has been changed to "/videos/video001".

Any suggestions? 
How to debug this situation or at least get any useful error message?

**UPDATE**
This article describe exact current situation and gives some solutions: http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ember-routing-the-when-and-why-of-nesting

Comment: suggestion, in chrome console (keep it open as you're loading the app), expand the `error while processing route` message, it should have a stack that could help you point where the error is. Question: Why isn't `slide` a resource of `videos.video`?

Comment: That stack trace is not helpful at all. List of internal methods of ember.js ember-data.js and jquery. 

I can't have 'slide' nested under 'video' because i need render it in application outlet. If i will user render hook and specify "into":"application", i will have another bunch of issues related to maintaining view hierarchy.

Comment: Nest the resource slide in your video resource

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar but without the multiple IDs. Try this in your router:

```
this.resource('videos', { path: '/videos' }, function () {
    this.resource('video', { path: '/:video_id' });

    this.resource('videos.video.slide', { path: '/videos/:video_id/:slide_id' });
});
```

Your routes should be `App.VideosRoute`, `App.VideosVideoRoute`, and `App.VideosVideoSlideRoute`. Same for the controllers (if needed)

Comment: checking.. Could you explain a little, why what is the difference between my and this solution?

Comment: That solution change behavior in a strange way, but didn't help.

Comment: @pro100sanya what you want to do is possible. The issue is naming the routes in such a way that the Ember resolver can locate it. I asked a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331816/route-not-seeing-url-slug and that is what my answer is based off. I've altered my answer to hopefully better explain what has worked for me and also nested the `slides` route under videos. When I have some time tonight I can try and get a JSBin working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I wasn't able to figure out what is the issue, and seems to be nobody able to help with that even on  ember irc channel. So I have found interesting article http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ember-routing-the-when-and-why-of-nesting and implemented nesting via {into: 'application'}, but to make it work correctly i have overrided renderTemplate hook in all templates to define correct rendering order. 
And everything works fine.